# delete duplicate meta_value with same post_id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, database, post-meta, duplicates

I've trying to cut down on the time to query a custom post type. After looking at the database and the wp_postmeta table, for some reason, there is some duplicate meta values for the same post_id and meta_key. The only difference is the meta_id.

Nacin talks about this here http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-meta-ID-td572.html

Some of these duplicates are pretty large. I bet if I were to get rid of them, I would cut the  size of the wp_postmeta table down to 1/3 of the size which hopefully will make my query faster.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get rid of duplicates and why they may exists? It's only happening on a some specific meta data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After investigating, I realized that it was left over from some fields that I no longer used so I was able to get rid of them.